# My string isn't printing

Tags: string, assembly, printing, x86-16, dos

I am doing an Assembly Calculator, and I need to do a Menu, but my program only prints the first string.

```
 TITLE  CALCULADORA
.MODEL  SMALL
.STACK  100H
.DATA

;menu

MENU    DB  'MENU$'
MSOMA   DB  'Digite 1 para Soma$'
MSUB    DB  'Digite 2 para Subtração$'

.CODE

MAIN PROC

    MOV     AX,@DATA    ;Localizacao do endereco de memoria das variaveis, e colocando-os en AX
    MOV     DS,AX       ;transferindo as dados da memoria em seu local padrao, no caso, DS (Data Stack)

    LEA     DX,MENU     ;Colocando o endereco do menu em DX
    MOV     AH,9        ;funçao de exibicao de string
    INT     21H         ;execucao de AH
    CALL    PULA_LINHA  ;"Chamando" a funcao PULA_LINHA

    LEA     DX,MSOMA    ;Colocando o endereco do menu em DX
    MOV     AH,9        ;funçao de exibicao de string
    INT     21H         ;execucao de AH
    CALL    PULA_LINHA  ;"Chamando" a funcao PULA_LINHA


MAIN ENDP   


PULA_LINHA PROC

    MOV     AH,2        ;inicia a funçao de leitura de caracter
    MOV     DL,0DH      ;caracter para o cursor retornar a posicao inicial
    INT     21H         ;executando o conteudo de AH, que por sua vez printa o conteudo de DL
    MOV     DL,0AH      ;caracter de descer a linha
    INT     21H         ;executando a tarefa

PULA_LINHA ENDP

    MOV     AH,4CH      ;saida do dos
    INT     21H         ;saindo


END  MAIN
```

Comment: You need a RET instruction at the end of each of your functions.

Comment: How could i do it?

Comment: First move the DOS exit interrupt `MOV     AH,4CH      ;saida do dos
    INT     21H         ;saindo`  code so that it is just before `main endp` and then place a `RET` instruction just before `PULA_LINHA ENDP`

Comment: now it works, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As Michael already mentioned in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46330951/my-string-on-assembly-isnt-printing#comment79624526_46330951), you "messed up" the returning functions a bit, and mistaken "return to OS" and "return to Caller":

```
 TITLE  CALCULADORA
.MODEL  SMALL
.STACK  100H
.DATA

;menu

MENU    DB  'MENU$'
MSOMA   DB  'Digite 1 para Soma$'
MSUB    DB  'Digite 2 para Subtração$'

.CODE

MAIN PROC

    MOV     AX,@DATA    ;Localizacao do endereco de memoria das variaveis, e colocando-os en AX
    MOV     DS,AX       ;transferindo as dados da memoria em seu local padrao, no caso, DS (Data Stack)

    LEA     DX,MENU     ;Colocando o endereco do menu em DX
    MOV     AH,9        ;funçao de exibicao de string
    INT     21H         ;execucao de AH
    CALL    PULA_LINHA  ;"Chamando" a funcao PULA_LINHA

    LEA     DX,MSOMA    ;Colocando o endereco do menu em DX
    MOV     AH,9        ;funçao de exibicao de string
    INT     21H         ;execucao de AH
    CALL    PULA_LINHA  ;"Chamando" a funcao PULA_LINHA

    ; ----------------------------------------------------------<<<<
    ; HERE you want to quit to OS, so the INT 21h/4Ch goes here
    MOV     AH,4CH      ;saida do dos
    INT     21H         ;saindo
    ; ----------------------------------------------------------<<<<


MAIN ENDP   


PULA_LINHA PROC

    MOV     AH,2        ;inicia a funçao de leitura de caracter
    MOV     DL,0DH      ;caracter para o cursor retornar a posicao inicial
    INT     21H         ;executando o conteudo de AH, que por sua vez printa o conteudo de DL
    MOV     DL,0AH      ;caracter de descer a linha
    INT     21H         ;executando a tarefa

    ; ----------------------------------------------------------<<<<
    ; HERE you just want to return to the caller, that's done with
    RET
    ; ----------------------------------------------------------<<<<

PULA_LINHA ENDP



END  MAIN
```